# Laravel Moloquent. Add projection to related model

Tags: laravel, jenssegers-mongodb, moloquent

I have a query with relation.

```php
$dbQuery = $this->someModel
    ->where('user_id', '<>', Auth::id())
    ->with(['questions'])
    ->get(['title', 'status', 'expired_at']);
```

The list of fields in `get()` method define the list of selected fields for the top level of selected data. But I need also add a projection to `questions` relation. How can I select only `questions._id` and `questions.description`?

I've tried to add this to `get()` list, but it not works in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that works for me based on @namelivia answer. It now works for me with `select`, but it works with `project`.

```php
Model1::with(['model2' => function($query){
    $query->project([
        'column1' => 1,
        'column2' => 1,
        'foreign_key' => 1 /* can not be excluded. */         
    ]);
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a closure with `with` for selecting just certain columns:

```php
Model1::with(['model2' => function($query){
    $query->select('column1','column2');
}])->get();
```

Comment: When tried with `select` as you mentioned it returns an empty array everytime. May be Moloquent does not suports `select`, don't know.